# Setting span html element text in C++

Tags: c++, firefox-addon

I am writing firefox extension using C++.
I want to set text of the span html element.

In Javascript, I used 'textcontent' javascript property to set span element text.

How can I do it in C++?

I found nsIDOMHTMLElement interface & its child interfaces.

They seem useful.

I am not getting the way in which I will use nsIDOMHTMLElement interface & its child interfaces to set span element text.

Please suggest me the way!

Thanks,
Vaibhav.

Answer (score 0):

cross-posted from http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/browse_frm/thread/7d96ca2fe4c2bd5a#